# How can I specify a memory location for constant array (C30 Compiler)

Tags: arrays, memory-management, pic, microchip

I am trying to place an array at the highest location in auxiliary memory on a PIC24EP256G810 processor using the Microchip C30 compiler.  The array is defined as follows:

```
const int __attribute__((space(auxflash), aligned(2048))) AuxFlashRows[8][128]
{
    {
        0x0000,etc,etc
    },
    {
        0x0000,etc,etc
    },
    etc
};
```

The code above will place the data in the auxiliary memory space, but I am unsure how to make the compiler place it at the highest location.  Just now it puts the array in a location occupied by the bootloader.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to modify the linker script.  You should just have to add the address() keyword in your **attribute** modifier, in addition to space() and aligned(), and hard-code the address you want.  It's documented in section 2.3.1 in my version of the C30 User's Guide, but either way you could just search the "**attribute**", where they are all documented together.  (Sorry, the form is eating my underscores :)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you have to adapt the linker file (p24EP256GU810.gld in  c30/support/pic24e/gld)

e.g. the program length segment:

program (xr)   : ORIGIN = 0x200,         LENGTH = 0x2A9FE

and reduce accordingly.